# Congress and US-Congress tag merge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

If you look at [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress), these are all about [us-congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-congress), and the latter tag is bigger.  So perhaps a merge from [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress)->[us-congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-congress) is in order?  I don't think a synonym is necessary, or desirable, since there can be non-US Congresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made [congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) the master tag.

I think locale tags would do a much better job of distinguishing questions for non US congresses. For example, I think [guatemala](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guatemala)[congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/congress) is a bit more useful than [guatemala-congress](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guatemala-congress).